# Is java.awt.color.RED an object or an attribute?

Tags: java

`Color.GREEN` looks like an attribute and not an object if so then how can I assign class member(`Color.GREEN`) to an object reference of type Color?

```
import java.awt.*;

public class StopLight {

    public static final Color GREEN = Color.GREEN;
    public static final Color YELLOW = Color.YELLOW;
    public static final Color RED = Color.RED;


    public StopLight() {
        state = GREEN;
    }

    private Color state;
}
```

Comment: What is an attribute? It is just like what you have in your example. It is a field of the type Color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a public static object defined in java awt's [`Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) :

```
/**
 * The color green.  In the default sRGB space.
 */
public final static Color green     = new Color(0, 255, 0);

/**
 * The color green.  In the default sRGB space.
 * @since 1.4
 */
public final static Color GREEN = green;
```

So you can access it as `Color.GREEN`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a *constant*, and of course an object of class `Color`.